# Installing Android SDK on Mac

Tags: android, macos

I'm extremly newish to Mac (now is the  first time I see this operating system) and I'm trying to install the Android SDK on it.

I've installed Android SDK before on Windows, but on Mac seems to be totally different, beginning with the fact that I don't have an `installer.exe` like on Windows which would tell me if I have a right JDK installed.

1. On Mac is needed to install a JDK to install? If yes, from where because in [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u26-download-400750.html) there seems to be no mention of `mac`, only `linux` and `windows`.
2. How can I verify if the right JDK is installed?

Thank you! I know this is something silly to ask, but I really don't manage.

Comment: By Android do you mean the Android SDK?

Comment: Verifying if Java is installed? Open terminal and type "java". You will know.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/richgossweiler/home/android-development-notes/installing-the-android-sdk-on-the-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install the JDK on Mac OS X. It is installed by default.

By using the `java -version` command line utility you can verify that the right version of Java is installed.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)  This is what I get when I type that command....Java HotSpot is a jdk file?Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After installing the SDK on a Mac running OS X Lion, I found the "android" command would not execute from the Terminal command line as shown in the instructions. I found an alternate set of installation instructions that solve the problem...

- Download the Android SDK for Macintosh
- Extract it
- Download Fastboot for OSX (If not included with SDK)
- Extract fastboot and place it in your /tools folder.
- Open up a terminal window
- type: pico .bash_profile (this will create a .bash_profile)
- type the following in the new screen: export PATH=$
  {PATH}:/tools
- Hit CNTRL + X
- Hit Y (for yes to save)
- It will return you to the terminal screen… type: exit
- Restart terminal.
- Then you can use your adb commands on the command line without adding "./"

Answer (score 1):

all the informations you need are on 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
and 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: There is nothing in there!only for windows:P...I asked for mac os x

Comment: These pages are about Windows AND Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

Until recently Apple provided the JDK so there was no separate install. Its still included in the current version of OS X but i think that changes with Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Mac software most certainly can have installers (I see one every time I install an update to some software, notably Microsoft Office) but a lot of applications are packaged so that installation is just a matter of dragging from the `.dmg` file to the Applications folder.

That said, you'll almost certainly have the right version of Java already installed under your `/System/Library` folder. You can see what versions you have installed (you may have multiple ones) using the `Java Preferences` app that is in the `/Applications/Utilities` folder.